# Handling conditional Angular Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make some API call if the status is 'ready' and then once only after that resolves  I want to execute some statements.

If the status is not `ready` I  don't want to make the API call but will still execute the statements.

I have it done it like this :

```
if(job.status === 'ready')
    //Makes a promise to fetch the progress API details for ready batches only
    var promise = HttpWrapper.send('/api/jobs/'+job.job_id+'/getDetails', { "operation": 'GET' });

//Once the promise is resolved, proceed with rest of the items
$q.all([promise])
.then(function(result) {
    //Because for not ready batches promise object and it's response wuld be undefined
    if(result[0] !== undefined){
        //Create a property that would hold the progress detail for ready batches
        job.pct = result[0].pct;
    }

    //Want to execute these lines no matter what
    vm.job = job;
    vm.loading = false;
```

I know I am making some bad coding practices here .

I may not need `$q.all` at all.

But I can't figure out how to handle the situation - because the last 2 lines would be executed

`For ready batches within then only after that promise resolves, but for other batches there is no promise. So they can get executed quickly.`

How can I effectively write them so that both the situations are handled?

Comment: You need an else block with those last 2 lines.

Comment: @DeepthiS I want them to execute for if block also.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, for lines to execute regardless I recommend trying the `.finally` block. you can check the job status then call the job details function.

```js
if (job.status === 'ready') {
  getJobDetails(job);
} else {
  defaults(job);
}

function getJobDetails(job) {
  return $http.get('/api/jobs/' + job.job_id + '/getDetails')
    .then(function(resp) {
      if (resp) {
        job.pct = result[0].pct;
      }
    })
    .catch(funcition(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      vm.job = job;
      vm.loading = false;
    });
}

function defaults(job) {
  vm.job = job;
  vm.loading = false;
}
```

Comment: What happens when the status is not ready? It does not get called ever. I mean the getJobDetails Method.

Comment: I want to call then also. Just that it will be called instantaneously not inside of a promise.

Comment: what exactly do you want to call instantaneously? you can have a default function to be called regardless or as an else block